# Query Postgres Timestamp with Timezone wrong result

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-12

I have a table with a `time` column defined as

```
time TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

my database and the server have the timezone UTC

```
Tue Apr 20 18:22:50 UTC 2021
```

When I ran the following query

```sql
SELECT id, time AT TIME ZONE 'utc' AS "TZ: UTC", time AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/Berlin' AS "TZ: Berlin" FROM orders ORDER BY id DESC;
```

results to

```
 id  |           TZ: UTC            |          TZ: Berlin
-----+------------------------------+------------------------------
 600 | 2021-04-20 18:18:07.11372+00 | 2021-04-20 16:18:07.11372+00
```

I would have expected in the `TZ: Berlin` column is
`2021-04-20 20:18:07.11372+00`.
When I run the query

```sql
SELECT id, time AT TIME ZONE 'utc' AS "TZ: UTC", time AT TIME ZONE 'UTC+2' AS "TZ: UTC+2" FROM orders ORDER BY id DESC
```

which results to the expected

```
 id  |           TZ: UTC            |          TZ: UTC+2
-----+------------------------------+------------------------------
 600 | 2021-04-20 18:18:07.11372+00 | 2021-04-20 20:18:07.11372+00
```

At this time of the year (summer) the timezones `UTC+2` and `Europe/Berlin` are identical.

So what am I missing?

Kind regards

PS: The Version is

```sh
$ postgres -V postgres
postgres (PostgreSQL) 12.6
```

When I run

```sql
SELECT NOW() at time zone 'Europe/Berlin';
```

I get

```
          timezone
----------------------------
 2021-04-20 20:41:57.155641
```

Comment: You should really use `timestamp with time zone` instead of `timestamp`.  It will help you avoid these issues.

Comment: okay, I have a work-around, I have to change `time AT TIME ZONE `Europe/Berlin`  `(time AT TIME ZONE 'utc') AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/Berlin')`. But I would like to understand better what went wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Adding AT TIME ZONE to a timestamp **without time zone** merely adds the time zone to the timestamp.  In your case, the time was stored as:

`2021-04-20 18:18:07.11372`

Adding the UTC time zone didn't change the hour portion of the time because it matches your session time zone.

Adding the Europe/Berlin time zone had the following effect:

2021-04-20 18:18:07.11372 = the time in Berlin, so we subtract two hours to get the time in UTC.

The case of UTC+2 is even more confusing.  I suggest reading more about the [posix time specifications](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datetime-posix-timezone-specs.html).

Note this important bit:

> The positive sign is used for zones west of Greenwich.

It worked as you expected, but for the wrong reason.

This might make it more clear:

```
 SELECT t,
       t at time zone 'UTC' as utc,
       t at time zone 'Europe/Berlin' as berlin,
       t at time zone 'UTC+2' as somewhere_west_of_utc,
       t at time zone 'UTC-2' as berlinish
FROM (
  VALUES ('2021-04-20T12:00:00'::timestamp)
) as v(t);
          t          |          utc           |         berlin         | somewhere_west_of_utc  |       berlinish
---------------------+------------------------+------------------------+------------------------+------------------------
 2021-04-20 12:00:00 | 2021-04-20 12:00:00+00 | 2021-04-20 10:00:00+00 | 2021-04-20 14:00:00+00 | 2021-04-20 10:00:00+00
(1 row)
```

Again, I would strongly advise you to use `timestamp with time zone` where all the timestamps will be stored as UTC.

Comment: I think it is good to use `timestamp without time zone` if the application does time zone conversions. Use `timestamp with time zone` if you want to do time zone conversion in the database.

Answer (score 0):

If you execute `AT TIME ZONE` on a `timestamp without time zone`, you get the absolute time when a clock in that time zone shows that time.

When a clock in Berlin shows 18:00, it is 16:00 UTC.